# SQL SERVER passing getdate() or string date not working correctly

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2000

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_ME

@ID int, 
@ThisDate datetime = null

AS
SET NOCOUNT ON


IF @ThisDate IS NULL
BEGIN
    SET @ThisDate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
END

DECLARE @intErrorCode int,  
        @QBegin datetime, 
        @QEnd datetime

SELECT @intErrorCode = @@ERROR


IF @ThisDate BETWEEN '01/01/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), YEAR(@ThisDate))  
             AND '03/31/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), YEAR(@ThisDate))  

BEGIN
    Select @QBegin  = DATEADD(s,0,CAST ('10/01/'  AS varchar(6) ) + 
                      CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),DATEPART (year,@ThisDate)-1))

    Select @QEnd = DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@QBegin)+3,0))


    SELECT * FROM   QUERY 
    WHERE       MEID = @ID 
    AND         mydate >= @QBegin 
    AND         mydate <= @QEnd)
END

SELECT @intErrorCode = @@ERROR
IF (@intErrorCode <> 0) GOTO ErrHandler

ErrHandler:
        RETURN @intErrorCode
GO
```

It returns a dataset when you leave it blank and it assumes and fills in the date, however when you plug in a date it just states "The command completed successfully."

Any help would be more than appreciated.

Comment: 1) Don't use `sp_` as a prefix - this is reserved for MS use, and is less efficient to use, 2) is the date you're passing explicitly outside of the first 3 months of the year?

Comment: not sure but when i get stuck like this I'd print out this part: '01/01/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), YEAR(@ThisDate)) to make sure you're getting the value you expect.

Comment: Your if condition would be better expressed as `IF DATEPART(month,@ThisDate) between 1 and 3` - don't convert datetimes to strings unless you need to.

Comment: This is great I actually had that commented out for testing :)

Comment: Your condition could also be `IF DATEPART(quarter, @ThisDate) = 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a guess, you need to query the previous quarter's results, which would just be this query:

```
SELECT * FROM   QUERY 
    WHERE       MEID = @ID 
    AND         mydate >= DATEADD(quarter,DATEDIFF(quarter,'20010101',@ThisDate),'20001001'),
    AND         mydate <  DATEADD(quarter,DATEDIFF(quarter,'20010101',@ThisDate),'20010101'))
```

And get rid of that big if condition, etc.

You could also get rid of the first if, if you put `COALESCE(@ThisDate,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)` in the above, where I currently have `@ThisDate`.

I use the `DATEADD(quarter,DATEDIFF(quarter,'20010101',@ThisDate),'20001001')` pattern for a lot of datetime manipulation. It let's you achieve a lot in a few operations. In this case, it's the difference between the two dates (`'20010101','20001001'`) which is giving us the previous quarter.

---

You'll frequently encounter the DATEADD/DATEDIFF pattern in questions involving removing the time portion from a datetime value. The canonical version of this is `DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,@Date),0)`. But the pattern can be generally extended to work with any of the datetime components. If you choose `month` rather than `day`, you'll get midnight at the start of the first of the month (of the day you've supplied)

Where it gets tricky is when you use dates (instead of `0`), and especially if you don't use the same date for both calculations. This allows you to apply an additional offset that seems almost "free" - you're already using this construct to remove the time component, the fact that you can compute e.g. the last date in a quarter/month/etc is a bonus.

Comment: It is a long query for all quarters and the date basically you can put in from say '1/20/2007' if you wanted for the @ThisDate. So it does not just represent current date. I just want to be able to put in a date parameter that returns the dataset instead of just letting me know that it ran. It does that with a null run like this below. sp_Me 10 --- so it runs a getdate essentially

Comment: @Kris - it's not at all clear so far what you're trying to achieve. Perhaps if you could add some sample data to your question, give some examples of explicit date parameters you're passing in, and the results you're expecting. As I say, the above query will return all results from the previous quarter, which is the same as your current query does (provided the date is between Jan and Mar), but mine will find the previous quarter, based on any date throughout the year.

Comment: You solved the issue :)) COALESCE(@ThisDate,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)  did it I will able to get it to run from that. Thank you so much :) Now off to vbscript which I know nada about.... If you know how to pull a file from a https server with vbs and sql server 2000 - you would be King!!!!!!!

Comment: @Damien: `a >= b AND a < b`? I think something's wrong with `mydate` comparisons. Maybe you meant `...AND mydate < DATEADD(quarter, DATEDIFF(quarter, '20010101', @ThisDate) + 1, '20010101'))`?

Comment: @Andriy M - The two values to the right of the comparison are different. I originally had my second DATEADD/DATEDIFF pair working out the last day of the previous quarter ('20001231'), rather than the first day of the current quarter('20010101'). Then I decided to modify it so that it would also work if `mydate` contained a time component also. When dealing with datetimes, a `>=`, `<` pair is more common.

Comment: @Andriy - the two dates at the end of the lines are different, and as I say, I'm targeting last quarter, not this quarter. The first date is 1st October 2000, the second is 1st January 2001. Unfortunately, they do look pretty similar.

Comment: @Damien: Thanks, that's just what I failed to see at first. I edited your post so the difference could be more easily seen. You should have chosen some other dates for your query! :)

Comment: @Andriy - yes, sorry it wasn't so easy to see. Unfortunately, by default, I always use '20010101' as my base date. No real reason for it, just habit.

Comment: @Damien: To my shame, it turns out to be my fault that I've been trapped by the similarity, because apart from the code I hadn't read your answer carefully enough, or I would've seen the difference where you were explaining the pattern usage. Sorry for making a fuss about nothing.